# Is there a generalization of trimean to $n$-th order (central) moments?

Tags: robust, moments, efficiency

I think trimean is the cat's meow.  Is there a generalization of this idea to $n$-th order (central) moments?

Basically I live in a world where the pain of outliers vastly exceeds the pain of inefficiency.  The [reference](http://archive.org/stream/atomicnucleus032805mbp#page/n925/mode/2up) calls this "macrostatistics" although I've never heard this term until researching this question.

Comment: Reference section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimean gives "Evans 1955, Appendix G: Inefficient statistics, pp. 902–904." which suggests:
$\sigma\approx \frac{(\text{93-percent point}) - (\text{7-percent point})}{3}$
under the observation that in a normal distribution 86% of the data fall wiithin $m\pm 1.5\sigma$.

Comment: Sedimentologists have been cooking up ad hoc equivalents of moment measures for decades, e.g. Inman, D.L. 1952.  Measures for Describing the Size Distribution of Sediments. _Journal of Sedimentary Petrology_ 22: 125-145 but most of these measures predate widespread availability of calculators, let alone computers. For a more systematic alternative, consider L-moments e.g. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-moment

Comment: @NickCox Came to mention L-moments too... all I can do is upvote your comment.

Comment: Isn't this more closely related to L-estimators rather than L-moments?  I gather the two are closely related but at least superficially L-estimators seem way closer than L-moments?